# Getting default user input java

Tags: java

I would like to get user input and have a default value for the last value as 1. How do i do this?

```
private static void addone() {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    int y = scan.nextInt();
    int z = scan.next();
    System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z)
```

So if the user enter  1 1 2 the method would print 1 1 2.
Or the user enters 1 1 and the method prints 1 1 1

Comment: First change your **char z** to **char z = scan.next().charAt(0);**

Answer (score 1):

How I would solve it:

- Set default values for x, y, and z. By default, ints in Java have a default value of zero. So initializing `int x = 0;` and `int y = 0;` has no effect, but we do it so that the compiler does not complain about printing values that have not been initialized. Then initialize `z = 1;`
- Read one line via `String inputString = scan.nextLine();`
- Convert the line into an array of strings via the `split()` method. (splitting with spaces as our delimiter)
- Read in the first three values of the array into x, y , and z respectively.
- Catch any Exceptions thrown by wrapping the above statements in a Try-Catch block

Output (first line is input, second line is output from program):
    1
    1 0 1

```
1 1
1 1 1

1 4
1 4 1

1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class F {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    addone();
  }

  private static void addone() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputString = scan.nextLine();   // Read in a line

    int x = 0;  // Default value 0
    int y = 0;  // Default value 0
    int z = 1;  // Default value 1

    try {
      // Split the String by spaces
      String[] input = inputString.split(" ");

      // Get the first three integers from the list
      // If the list is longer, the rest will be
      // simply ignored. If the list is too short
      // an indexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown
      // but we will also catch it, and proceed with
      // the program
      x = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
      y = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
      z = Integer.parseInt(input[2]);

      // Catch a thrown Exception
    } catch (Exception e) {

      // Don't do anything.

    } 

    // Display the result:
    // If the Exception was thrown, the original
    // values will be printed, if there was no Exception
    // then the values will have been properly overriden
    System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + z);

  }
}
```